# Amazon product api call Response: SignatureDoesNotMatch in PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I am making a call like this to do some search in Amazon and the response I get back says

```
 SignatureDoesNotMatchThe request signature we calculated does not match
 thesignature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. 
 Consult the service documentation for details
```

Not sure why the signature is not matching..

```
    $base_url = "http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?";
     $url_params = array('Operation'=>"ItemSearch",'Service'=>"AWSECommerceService",
        'AWSAccessKeyId'=>$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,'AssociateTag'=>"dtsearch-20",
     'Version'=>"2013-08-01",'Availability'=>"Available",'Condition'=>"All",
             'ItemPage'=>"1",'ResponseGroup'=>"Images,ItemAttributes,EditorialReview",
       'Keywords'=>"Laptop");

  // Add the Timestamp
    $url_params['Timestamp'] = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.\\0\\0\\0\\Z", time());

   // Sort the URL parameters
  $url_parts = array();
   foreach(array_keys($url_params) as $key)
     $url_parts[] = $key."=".$url_params[$key];
      sort($url_parts);

   // Construct the string to sign
     $string_to_sign = "GET\ecs.amazonaws.com\n/onca/xml\n".implode("&",$url_parts);
   $string_to_sign = str_replace('+','%20',$string_to_sign);
   $string_to_sign = str_replace(':','%3A',$string_to_sign);
  $string_to_sign = str_replace(';',urlencode(';'),$string_to_sign);

     // Sign the request
 $signature = hash_hmac("sha256",$string_to_sign,$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,TRUE);

  // Base64 encode the signature and make it URL safe
   $signature = base64_encode($signature);
   $signature = str_replace('+','%2B',$signature);
   $signature = str_replace('=','%3D',$signature);

      $url_string = implode("&",$url_parts);
      $url = $base_url.$url_string."&Signature=".$signature;
      print $url;

      $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
      $xml_response = curl_exec($ch);
         curl_close($ch);

     echo $xml_response;
    ?>
```

I have looked at other posts related to this but not sure how to write a function in the same page... I cannot add more php files... so I need to have all the code in this one page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and see if you get the same signature:
http://associates-amazon.s3.amazonaws.com/signed-requests/helper/index.html

If the way you are computing it is correct there may be a clock difference between your machine and the amazon server. In that case you need to synchronize the time on your machine.